# MySQL view show data not in database

Tags: php, mysql, cloud

I have database on cloud server, in this days I am ambiguous from error of MySQL server, this database have 15 table and 6 views.

Error : when all tables are empty all views return a row with only 1 value on the other hand if you execute Query directly the answer of MySQL is empty!!

Note: database never have those values.

[image: execute view screen shot]

[image]

Comment: There might be something wrong with the view itself. Please also add the `CREATE` statement that made the view. You can get the statement using the `SHOW CREATE VIEW` syntax (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-view.html).

Comment: **View has been changed Why?**

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`userdb`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vimelkmap` AS select 1 AS `id`,1 AS `cityId`,1 AS `title`,1 AS `price`,1 AS `ejareh`,1 AS `Rahn`,1 AS `closed`,1 AS `publish`,1 AS `mapLoc`,1 AS `transId`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the View statement. There's no `FROM` so whatever happens the view will return a row of `1`s.